# soap service with spring-boot & mtom from an existing wsdl

Tags: java, spring-boot, wsdl, spring-ws, mtom

Following this example (https://codenotfound.com/spring-ws-example.html) I'm trying to create a `SOAP` service with `spring-boot 2.2.0.RELEASE` starting from an existing `WSDL`.

The point is that in the output class there is a field that must be sent via `MTOM` and I cannot get it to work properly. With the following excerpt from my code, a response is returned with the `base64` within the field `<data>`.

```java
//Configuration bean class
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<Servlet> messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(servlet, "/ServiceWS/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "DeliveryService")
    public Wsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition() {
        return new SimpleWsdl11Definition(new ClassPathResource("/wsdl/DeliveryService.wsdl"));
    }

    // other stuff
}

// Endpoint class

@Endpoint
public class DeliverDocumentEndpoint {
    @PayloadRoot(namespace = "http://pb.com/service/ws/delivery", localPart = "DeliverDocument")
    @ResponsePayload
    public DeliverDocumentResponse deliverDocument(@RequestPayload DeliverDocument request) throws DeliveryFault {
        // DO STUFF WITH MTOM
    }
}
// Field int output bean, via code generation

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ComposedDocument", propOrder = {"data"})
public class ComposedDocument {
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlMimeType("application/octet-stream")
    protected DataHandler data;
    // getter and setter
}
```

looking on the web I found an example (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws-samples/tree/master/mtom) and I added another `@Configuration` bean to my solution,

```java
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class MtomServerConfiguration extends WsConfigurationSupport {
    @Bean
    @Override
    public DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter defaultMethodEndpointAdapter() {
        List<MethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers = new ArrayList<>();
        argumentResolvers.add(methodProcessor());
        List<MethodReturnValueHandler> returnValueHandlers = new ArrayList<>();
        returnValueHandlers.add(methodProcessor());
        DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter adapter = new DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter();
        adapter.setMethodArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
        adapter.setMethodReturnValueHandlers(returnValueHandlers);
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor methodProcessor() {
        return new MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor(marshaller());
    }

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath("com.pb.service.ws.model");
        marshaller.setMtomEnabled(true);
        return marshaller;
    }
}
```

however with this approach I got this falut:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
    <faultstring xml:lang="en">
        No adapter for endpoint 
        [public com.pb.service.ws.delivery.DeliverDocumentResponse it.m2sc.ws.endpoint.DeliverDocumentEndpoint.deliverDocument(com.pb.service.ws.delivery.DeliverDocument) 
        throws com.pb.service.ws.delivery.DeliveryFault]: 
        Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint, or does it implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint?
    </faultstring>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
```

**How can I solve the problem ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**: when generate-sources plugin was running, the sources generated was splitted in 3 different packages. I had to list them all to Jaxb2Marshaller like this:

```
@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com.pb.service.ws.common", "com.pb.service.ws.delivery", "com.pb.service.ws.model");
    marshaller.setMtomEnabled(true);
    return marshaller;
}
```